# Header PDF por JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como passar o header PDF através de JavaScript/jQuery?

Preciso imprimir uma página, ou seja, quando o usuário acessar a mesma, ele já envia o header PDF e manda para download. Como fazer isso por JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **sintaxe** para envio de um cabeçalho de requisição com a jQuery seria:

```
$.ajax({

    url: "/path/to/file.ext",
    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {

        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-type', 'application/pdf' );
    }

}).done( function( response ) {

    // Dom something
})
```

No entanto, salvo engano, isso não terá o resultado intendido pois é um *Request Header*, ou seja, ele indica ao programa receptor, definido na URL do AJAX que uma requisição em PDF estaria sendo feita, ao invés de um *Response Header* que diz ao browser para tratar aquele *output* como um PDF.

Nunca vi nenhuma aplicação prática, mas eu imagino que enviando esse *Request Header* permitiria a aplicação receptora trabalhar com a *raw data* ("dados crus") da Requisição.